# Extrair dados com operadores bitshift e bitwise

Tags: c, bitwise

Boas, estou a ter alguns problema na separação das partes da data através de operações bitwise.

date format: yyyy-dd-mm

```
int menor_data(int date1, int date2)
{    
    int day1 = (date1 >> 8) & 0xff;
    int month1 = date1 & 0xff;
    int year1 = (date1 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int day2 = (date2 >> 8) & 0xff;
    int month2 = date2 & 0xff;
    int year2 = (date2 >> 16) & 0xff;
}
```

O problema é que quando faço print por exemplo de year1 não tem nada a ver com o ano data 1. Penso que estou a fazer confusão, pois as datas estão em base 10 e a máscara está em base 16

Comment: Por favor, mostre um exemplo completo que inclua as entradas que você passa para a função `menor_data` (além do resultado obtido e do esperado)

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários problemas no seu código. O principal deles é a ordem de utilização dos **operadores de *bitwise*** e **operadores de *bitshift*** que estão invertidas.

A única forma de garantir que você entende como extrair determinados conjuntos de bits de um inteiro é fazendo justamente o contrário: **implementar uma função para compactar a data em um número inteiro**:

```
int gerar_data(char dia, char mes, short int ano) 
{
    int y_d_m = 0; // yyyyddmm
    y_d_m |= (ano & 0xFFFF) << 16;
    y_d_m |= (dia & 0xFF) << 8;
    y_d_m |= (mes & 0xFF) ;

    //printf("ydm = %d\n", y_d_m );
    return y_d_m ;
}
```

Agora a segunta parte do problema é resolvida mais facilmente: basta usar operadores contrários de *bitshift* e atualizar as máscaras de bit que são usadas com o operador *bitwise* **&**:

```
int menor_data(int date1, int date2)
{    
    int year1  = (date1 & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
    int day1   = (date1 & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    int month1 = (date1 & 0xFF);

    // ...
}
```